# Can an exe built on .net 2.0 refer to a dll built on .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I have an exe which has to be built in .Net 2.0

Can this exe refer a dll built on .Net 4.0 ?

When I try to do that I get compilation error saying "referring dll not found"

Comment: why does it need to be built as 2.0, specifically? (as this may impact the answer)

Comment: its underlying  framework exe, developed by different team. They can't migrate to 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can reference Assemblies built with earlier versions, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

> Can this exe refer a dll built on .Net 4.0 ?

No. The .NET framework is backwards compatible, not upwards compatible which seems normal. In order to use an assembly compiled against .NET 4.0 you need to run your application under the CLR 4.0.

So to recap:

- you can mix .NET 2.0 up to .NET 4.0 assemblies when the application runs in CLR 4.0
- you can mix .NET 2.0 up to .NET 3.5 assemblies when the application runs in CLR 2.0 (which is your case since the executable is compiled against .NET 2.0)

Comment: Best one word answer I've seen in a while.